# Can I have a JPA Project Jar inside a WebAPP lib directory?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I want to create a JPA project common for two websites projects that I will create. If I use the jar exported from the jpa project as a library in the web1 and web2. Can I still have the JPA functionality?

```
Eclipse Workspace
|_JPA Project
|_Web1 Project
|__WEB-INF
|___lib
|____JPA.jar
|_Web2 Project
|__WEB-INF
|___lib
|____JPA.jar
```

Comment: Yes you can. Please try it first before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as you have the persistence.xml file located on the META-INF folder on your JPA project it should work ok

Comment: I'll test it tonight and let you know.

Comment: Yes.Eclipse detect that JPA Project was added as a dependecy in the WEB Project, so it made JPA Project libs be exportes to ../lib instead of /lib. Summary: My JPA Project libs can be used in my webapps, and JPA works like a charm.